# BootStrap Full Calendar CSS on cell

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap calendar, I wanted to color the cell as green if its timestamp is bigger than today

which is

```
$checkTime > $today
cell.css = green background
```

I saw this code at stackoverflow

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

I tried add it into after

```
                        defaultView: 'month',
```

so it become

```
defaultView: 'month',
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var today = new Date();
    if (date.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
        cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
},
```

If I add in dayRender, it won't work. The calendar won't display

This is my code for full calendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: '<?php echo $today;?>',
                        defaultView: 'month',
            editable: false,
            events: [
                <?php echo $calendar_html;?>
            ],
 eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }

});

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Added this to my inpage style

```
.fc-before-today {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

And added

className: 'fc-before-today'

to my events and its work well :) Found the answer after 1 hour of googling